# what is a difference between React Native Notifications vs notifee vs react-native-push-notification

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, diff

I want to implement push notifications in my react native app quickly which of these libraries will work? and make my work easier I don't know how they work and the difference in them.

Comment: What have you chosen?

Comment: I'm using rn firebase it fulfilled my needs. Afaik notifee is more advanced and used for custom notifications. Dont know much about the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Notifee:

> Notifee is a library for React Native, bringing local notification support to both Android & iOS applications.

react-native-push-notification :
for Local and Remote Notifications for iOS and Android - not maintaned

react-native-notifications: same as react-native-push-notifications - maintaned

looks like react-native-notifications is the best to handle both local and remote notificaitons